# Chatter likes - how to get user likes per record?

Tags: chatter

I have a requirement where for a given record need display the number chatter likes and dislikes for each user.

I have tried to use userfeed object it is not giving data about specific record. It is a sum of all like or dislike for  all the records by the particular user.

Is there any way to acheive this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get at this data via the [ConnectAPI](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcodepre/Content/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm) - this is an example using Winter 15/API 32 - summer 14 is a bit different but you can see the idea - set the Id in line one, and you can loop through likes for all feed items in that feed:

```
//Get all Feed Elements from a Record
ConnectApi.FeedElementPage fep = ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(null, ConnectApi.FeedType.Record, 'a00B0000001eeiu');

//Build list of Likes for Element in Feed
List<ConnectApi.ChatterLikePage> clp = new List<ConnectApi.ChatterLikePage>();

//Loop through results from Feed and add each Chatter Likes Page to List
for (ConnectApi.FeedElement fe: fep.elements) {
     clp.add(ConnectAPI.ChatterFeeds.getLikesForFeedElement(null, fe.Id));
    }

//Loop through likes for each element in feed and get each user who liked liked that element
for (ConnectApi.ChatterLikePage cltemp: clp) {
    for (ConnectApi.ChatterLike clike: cltemp.items) {
        //Show User Id for the like for this Feed Element
        system.debug(clike.user.Id);    
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things to note about the example: (1) - Both the getFeedElementsFromFeed() and getLikesForFeedElement() methods are paged, and because they don't specify page sizes, the default page size of 25 is used. So if you've got more than 25 feed elements in your feed, or more than 25 likes on a feed element, some of the counts will be off. You could implement paging and larger page sizes. (2) - You could use a similar technique to get the likes for each comment too, if that's required.